# cocos2dx android AppDelegate Error while linking

Tags: android, c++, cocos2d-x-2.x

Hi I have problem compiling project for android - it works ok for win32 and BB10 
but when I try to compile it in android NDK iget following Messages:

```
[armeabi] SharedLibrary  : libcocos2dcpp.so
C:/androidsdk/ndk/android-ndk-r10/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.9/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld.exe: error: ./obj/local/armeabi/objs/cocos2dcpp_shared/__/__/Classes/AppDelegate.o: multiple definition of 'AppDelegate::applicationDidEnterBackground()'
C:/androidsdk/ndk/android-ndk-r10/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.9/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld.exe: ./obj/local/armeabi/objs/cocos2dcpp_shared/__/__/Classes/AppDelegate.o: previous definition here
C:/androidsdk/ndk/android-ndk-r10/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.9/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld.exe: error: ./obj/local/armeabi/objs/cocos2dcpp_shared/__/__/Classes/AppDelegate.o: multiple definition of 'AppDelegate::applicationWillEnterForeground()'
C:/androidsdk/ndk/android-ndk-r10/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.9/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld.exe: ./obj/local/armeabi/objs/cocos2dcpp_shared/__/__/Classes/AppDelegate.o: previous definition here
C:/androidsdk/ndk/android-ndk-r10/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.9/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld.exe: error: ./obj/local/armeabi/objs/cocos2dcpp_shared/__/__/Classes/AppDelegate.o: multiple definition of 'vtable for AppDelegate'
C:/androidsdk/ndk/android-ndk-r10/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.9/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld.exe: ./obj/local/armeabi/objs/cocos2dcpp_shared/__/__/Classes/AppDelegate.o: previous definition here
C:/androidsdk/ndk/android-ndk-r10/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.9/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld.exe: error: ./obj/local/armeabi/objs/cocos2dcpp_shared/__/__/Classes/AppDelegate.o: multiple definition of 'AppDelegate::AppDelegate()'
C:/androidsdk/ndk/android-ndk-r10/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.9/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld.exe: ./obj/local/armeabi/objs/cocos2dcpp_shared/__/__/Classes/AppDelegate.o: previous definition here
C:/androidsdk/ndk/android-ndk-r10/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.9/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld.exe: error: ./obj/local/armeabi/objs/cocos2dcpp_shared/__/__/Classes/AppDelegate.o: multiple definition of 'AppDelegate::AppDelegate()'
C:/androidsdk/ndk/android-ndk-r10/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.9/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld.exe: ./obj/local/armeabi/objs/cocos2dcpp_shared/__/__/Classes/AppDelegate.o: previous definition here
C:/androidsdk/ndk/android-ndk-r10/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.9/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld.exe: error: ./obj/local/armeabi/objs/cocos2dcpp_shared/__/__/Classes/AppDelegate.o: multiple definition of 'AppDelegate::loadResources()'
C:/androidsdk/ndk/android-ndk-r10/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.9/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld.exe: ./obj/local/armeabi/objs/cocos2dcpp_shared/__/__/Classes/AppDelegate.o: previous definition here
C:/androidsdk/ndk/android-ndk-r10/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.9/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld.exe: error: ./obj/local/armeabi/objs/cocos2dcpp_shared/__/__/Classes/AppDelegate.o: multiple definition of 'AppDelegate::applicationDidFinishLaunching()'
C:/androidsdk/ndk/android-ndk-r10/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.9/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld.exe: ./obj/local/armeabi/objs/cocos2dcpp_shared/__/__/Classes/AppDelegate.o: previous definition here
C:/androidsdk/ndk/android-ndk-r10/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.9/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld.exe: error: ./obj/local/armeabi/objs/cocos2dcpp_shared/__/__/Classes/AppDelegate.o: multiple definition of 'typeinfo name for AppDelegate'
C:/androidsdk/ndk/android-ndk-r10/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.9/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld.exe: ./obj/local/armeabi/objs/cocos2dcpp_shared/__/__/Classes/AppDelegate.o: previous definition here
C:/androidsdk/ndk/android-ndk-r10/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.9/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld.exe: error: ./obj/local/armeabi/objs/cocos2dcpp_shared/__/__/Classes/AppDelegate.o: multiple definition of 'typeinfo for AppDelegate'
C:/androidsdk/ndk/android-ndk-r10/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.9/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld.exe: ./obj/local/armeabi/objs/cocos2dcpp_shared/__/__/Classes/AppDelegate.o: previous definition here
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
/cygdrive/c/androidsdk/ndk/android-ndk-r10/build/core/build-binary.mk:647: recipe for target 'obj/local/armeabi/libcocos2dcpp.so' failed
```

Can anyone teel point me what im doing wrong?
cocos 2.4

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I also had the same problem with another library. In my case, it was because in Android.mk, in LOCAL_SRC_FILES, the same c file was listed 2 times. In your case it might be AppDelegate.cpp

Comment: I accidentally added a duplicate item... This reminder saved a ton of my bacon. Just get your source includes list. sort it and then double check. look for the dupes right next to one another. You won't any more time on it after you do that!!! I wish I had taken my own advice there. (Note to future self. Stop making this mistake already!)